# Use Windows API Callback to retrieve Network Adapter Status

Tags: c, winapi, callback

I use the lines of code below (not that important for my question) to retrieve the current status of the existing network adapters. See the comment marked "HERE".
This works fine and it prints this text:
[image]

But I like to use a Callback or similar in C instead of my current code. I like to know if there is a way Windows 7 can alarm me, if the OperationStatus of one of my network adapters has changed? My problem is I dont know how to start.

```
#include <stdafx.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iptypes.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

const ULONG MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 15000;

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAdapterAddresses = NULL;
    ULONG                                 bufferSize = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

    pAdapterAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *) MALLOC(bufferSize);

    GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, 0, NULL, pAdapterAddresses, & bufferSize);

    do{


        std::wcout<<"Name:\t\t\t "<<pAdapterAddresses->Description<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"OperationStatus:\t "<<pAdapterAddresses->OperStatus<<std::endl;
        //HERE: prints network adapter status       

        if(pAdapterAddresses->Next != 0){
            pAdapterAddresses = pAdapterAddresses->Next;
            std::cout<<"\n";}
    } while(pAdapterAddresses->Next != 0);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On [Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700376.aspx) or on [earlier versions of Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: sorry Windows 7; Edited in the question

Comment: @arx: That looks like a good start on an answer.